# Passing Cpp object to swift

Tags: c++, swift, interop

I have a macOS app project implementing the direct Cpp-swift interop mechanism. The project some cpp classes and few Swift class. **I wanted to pass a cpp object to a swift function as parameter, so I can use it in my swift code. But the documentation is not very clear on how to do this. Can some please share a code snippet explaining how can I achieve this**?

I have tried the below code, but it is giving linker error.

**Swift code:**

```
import StClass_modulemap
public class SwiftClass {
..
   public static func getCppObj (pObj: inout StClass) -> Void
    {
...
    }
}
```

**Cpp code:**

```
#include "Student.hpp"
#include "StClass.hpp"
#include <InteropLib-Swift.h> 

using namespace InteropLib;

void Student::Introduce() {
    
    
    //creating cpp to be passed to swift
    // StClass StObj(50);

   //  Teacher::getCppObj(StObj);
    
    std::cout<< "header included in hpp " <<std::endl;
}
```

calling Student::Introduce is giving a linker error for StClass

Comment: I think you need to create a bridge with Objective-C and then call from Swift to Objective-C.

Comment: @son Not anymore https://www.swift.org/documentation/cxx-interop/

Comment: Does [this](https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-pass-swift-object-to-c-method/67025/8) help?